# Error during compilation of CoreLibs Foundation

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I'm trying to build the Swift Foundation workspace in Xcode using the [instructions](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/GettingStarted.md), but the build fails as shown below:
[image]

I'm running Xcode `9.0.1`, Sierra `10.12.6` and Swift 4. I've also installed the Swift 4.0 toolchain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update to Xcode 9.2.

Comment: You also need to be working with a master snapshot of the Swift toolchain (https://swift.org/download/#snapshots), not a release Swift 4 toolchain (that's the one Xcode will ship with anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the [swift development toolchain](https://swift.org/builds/development/xcode/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2018-01-21-a/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2018-01-21-a-osx.pkg) and added it in xcode. I can now successfully build and run tests. Thanks Hamish :)